# Call function when ad is clicked in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i wanna do is call a function when an ad is clicked. It is a banner ad from an ad network. For other things i can easily use onclick but on an ad its not working because it is fetched using a script.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRGCv.png)

And furthermore that ad script creates iframe in which there is image and link.
I have tried several methods but none worked.

Comment: You can try "live events": `$( "element-containing-ad" ).on( "click", "ad-element", function() {})`. It works fine on dynamic elements

Comment: maybe you can try to put your ads in a `div` container then add a click event listener to that div